3ds max maxscript transfer animation
for maxscript
how to copy animation from bone_1 to bone_2 with global mode?
I mean like a save load animation feature and then just "Exposed World Transfrom" the animation is copied globally, not locally
this is an example of what i don't want, it copies the animation with local mode :
b2 = $bone_1
b1 = $bone_2
--instance controllers
global track

for i = 1 to 3 do b2[3][i].track = b1[3][i].track
--copy controllers
for i = 1 to 3 do b2[3][i].track = copy b1[3][i].track

